# unsigned int T = 0xFFFFFFFF equals to -1 in C?? it should not work as 2 compliment right after unsigned?

Tags: c

unsigned int is the same as  uint32_t? which is 32 bits of unsigned integers and not 2 compliment right?

```
uint32_t y = 0xFFFFFFFF;   // gives -1  i dont get why is it negative?
uint8_t x = 0b11111111;    // gives 255 i understand this
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gives -1"?  Can you add some code that shows this to your question?

Comment: And how are you printing it out?

Comment: `uint32_t y = 0xFFFFFFFF;` is the same as `uint32_t y = -1;`, but it is a positive value (`2^32 - 1`). How did you print it to get `-1` output?

Comment: "compliment" is not the word you are looking for. "complementer" is.

Comment: "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"...

Comment: Maybe the question should be, what compiler are you using.

Comment: @DanielFischer Some nice UB and `printf("%" PRId32, y);` does the trick.

Comment: @H2CO3 Or, with high probability, `printf("%d\n", y);` will do it. But there are several possible ways, not all of them involve UB.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, yes. (But honestly, I can't suddenly think of a way that doesn't.)

Comment: @H2CO3 `union { int32_t sig; uint32_t uns; } u; u.uns = y; printf("%" PRId32 "\n", u.sig);`

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, yes, good ol' type punning. (But wait, isn't signed integer overflow UB as well? not like it wouldn't work, but still.)

Comment: @H2CO3 There's no overflow in that, you just reinterpret the bit pattern. Since `int32_t` (if it exists) doesn't have trap representations, you're guaranteed to get a valid value.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's good news.

Comment: @DanielFischer: And moreover, `intNN_t` is guaranteed, if it exists, to have a twos-complement representation and full negative range.

Answer (score 7):

The bit pattern you are showing represents -1 for a signed integer, and the maximum value if it is representing an unsigned integer.

When you say it "gives -1", you should look at how you check that. If, for example, you print it with printf, you should make sure to use an unsigned format specifier.

Answer (score -1):

> uint32_t y = 0xFFFFFFFF;   // gives -1  i dont get why is it negative?

The reason why it is negative is, because, by definition, any number where the highes sigfnificant bit is set, is to be interpreted as negative, when a signed type is used. In your case the value would be normally not considered to be negative, as uint is considered unsigned.

Consequently this means that  for example:

0xFFFF is -1 when considered as a 16bit integer, but the same value is not negative when using a 32 bit integer.

The compiler is extending the signedness if the appropriate conversions are used. So the above value, would still become -1 if it is appropriately promoted to a 32bit int.

Comment: -1 it is not negative. OP was probably invoking UB by trying to print it with `printf("%d", ...)`.